# How should we tag questions about making magic items?

Tags: discussion, tags

In order of their folksonomic creation, we currently have the tags
[magic-items](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/magic-items) (May 16, 2011), 
[crafting](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/crafting) (Oct 1, 2014), and 
[magic-item-creation](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/magic-item-creation) (May 26 of this year).

Notably, the more general [crafting](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/crafting) tag lays claim to “… smithing, alchemy, **magic item creation**…”, while the newer [magic-item-creation](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/magic-item-creation) obviously lays full claim to magic item creation.

In the wild these are being used in a few combinations:

- [magic-items](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/magic-items)[crafting](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/crafting) [<sup>*search*</sup>](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/magic-items+crafting+-magic-item-creation) (most common, being the oldest tags)
- [magic-item-creation](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/magic-item-creation) [<sup>*search*</sup>](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/magic-item-creation+-magic-items+-crafting)
- [magic-items](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/magic-items)[magic-item-creation](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/magic-item-creation) [<sup>*search*</sup>](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/magic-items+magic-item-creation+-crafting)
- (*no question uses all three*) [<sup>*search*</sup>](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/magic-items+crafting+magic-item-creation)

This is pretty inconsistent. It makes it a guessing game what tags to use when asking, editing, and searching. I think we should probably fix that.

What should our tagging convention be for questions about making magic items?

Answer (score 13):

Use [crafting](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/crafting) whenever it's about any character crafting any object, and [magic-items](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/magic-items) whenever magic items are key. Whenever systems have commonality between different types of crafting, it's better to use a single tag instead of splitting between two different crafting-specific tags, whereas whenever there's a difference, the system tag and [magic-items](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/magic-items) should always be able to distinguish well enough to make searching and tag following effective.

[magic-item-creation](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/magic-item-creation) should just be burninated. It's nothing more than a specific combination of two other tags, like having [dnd-3.5e-classes](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dnd-3.5e-classes).

Comment: Burninated, or synonymed to [crafting]? If we're to get rid of [magic-item-creation] I'm leaning toward making it a synonym so that it shows up when people type `mag`… into the tags field.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie: Well, I have no real objections to a synonym.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie I'd suggest you go with burninate.  That tag (MIC) never needed to happen.  The tag crafting covers all crafting, and if you need to add specificity, magic item is already there to add that key word *where needed.*

Comment: @KorvinStarmast It's true it never needed to be created. Now it's here though, the reasoning for synonyming is as follows: It'd be nice to catch the people who type `creation`, as well as maybe catch the people who tag with [[tag:magic-items]] who *haven't* been adding any crafting/creation tag to magic item crafting questions (that happens a lot). With [[tag:magic-item-creation]] as an existing tag synonym, more people will see that hey, they should use that (which has been happening), and more people will use it and get the [[tag:crafting]] tag properly applied without editors' intervention.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie It's been used 12 times.  I'll be happy to delete that tag and replace it on the questions where it was used (12 times) with "crafting" and "magic items" and then you can burninate it.

Comment: @KorvinStarmast Oh, that's what you're getting at. Unfortunately “burnination” isn't an official process. Mods can't blacklist a tag, only synonym it or remove it manually. “Burnination” is the colloquial term for making a tag go away entirely by manually removing it, and waiting for the system to auto-delete its record. It doesn't prevent re-creation. Blacklisting is for extreme cases (e.g. [rules]). Synonyming is a good way to prevent tag re-creation, but only in cases where it is semantically useful. So the choice is (synonym) vs. (manual removal + no other step).

Comment: @SevenSidedDie OK, then I got nuthin'  As there are a total of 12 instances, I don't see it as a problem, but I think you are trying to prevent one later in tag usage.

Comment: @KorvinStarmast Yeah, with only a few posts to retag it won't be difficult either way, so I'm more looking at future utility. Though come to think, even that can could be kicked down the road, in the sense that we could just remove/retag now, and if an unwanted tag is re-created later it can always be synonymed later.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie: Well, this just hit a score of 10; should we go ahead and burn now?

Answer (score 2):

Since it appears it's going to get removed one way or another, I'm going to just put a list here of the questions that had the [magic-item-creation](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/magic-item-creation) tag at this point for historical record:

- [Can a Ioun Stone be made cracked?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/91651/can-a-ioun-stone-be-made-cracked)
- [What is the price to deliberately create a cracked Ioun Stone?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/91659/what-is-the-price-to-deliberately-create-a-cracked-ioun-stone)
- [Skill checks for Magic Item Creation](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/90793/skill-checks-for-magic-item-creation)
- [By how much is a wand's price raised if unicorn horn is added during its creation?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/90809/by-how-much-is-a-wands-price-raised-if-unicorn-horn-is-added-during-its-creatio)
- [If a wondrous item was dynamically created as slimy, can I remove the smell with prestidigitation?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/90190/if-a-wondrous-item-was-dynamically-created-as-slimy-can-i-remove-the-smell-with)
- [How do I price command-word activated items?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/88297/how-do-i-price-command-word-activated-items)
- [Can a machinesmith take Scribe Scroll?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/88155/can-a-machinesmith-take-scribe-scroll)
- [How much do multiple weapon enchantments cost?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/86322/how-much-do-multiple-weapon-enchantments-cost)
- [Are there any rules for creating intelligent items by PC's in 3.5E? If not..., please help!](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/84296/are-there-any-rules-for-creating-intelligent-items-by-pcs-in-3-5e-if-not-p)
- [Magic Item Creation and round usages rules instead of duration](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/83963/magic-item-creation-and-round-usages-rules-instead-of-duration)
- [How much does a shield that is also a magic weapon cost?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/80755/how-much-does-a-shield-that-is-also-a-magic-weapon-cost)
- [Can a shield that has both armor and attack enhancements exceed +10 total enhancement?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/80753/can-a-shield-that-has-both-armor-and-attack-enhancements-exceed-10-total-enhanc)